# How to get table(entity) size in room?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, android-database

It's easy to get the database size but it also includes tables which I don't require when I'm doing it for my analytical study. What I want to know is if there is any easy way to get the table size specifying by it's name in room database?

```
@Dao
interface ImageDataDao {


    @Query("SELECT * FROM localimagedata  order by image_name limit 1")
    fun getFirst(): LiveData<LocalImageData>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM localimagedata  order by image_name limit 10")
    fun getFirstTen(): List<LocalImageData>


  }
```

like table size of localimagedata that I'm currently storing in my database?